# Build mono for fedora 20 no xbuild

Tags: linux, build, mono, fedora, configure

I'm currently trying to update my mono, gtk-sharp and monodevelop environment, since I need to build with gstreamer-sharp 0.99.x which needs the new bindings.
So no problem I thought. Downloaded mono, unpacked it and started the normal toolchain.
But mono doesn't build xbuild for me. mono is build and has the correct version, but I couldn't test it, since I would say, something is missing, if xbuild is not build.

How can this happen?

config.log (errors only mentioned):

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files

gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files

conftest.c:11:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ac_nonexistent.h>

conftest.c:58:24: fatal error: sys/sockio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/sockio.h>

conftest.c:27:23: fatal error: sys/utime.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/utime.h>

conftest.c:64:23: fatal error: sys/mkdev.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/mkdev.h>

conftest.c:31:23: fatal error: sys/mkdev.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/mkdev.h>

conftest.c:66:21: fatal error: libproc.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libproc.h>

conftest.c:94:20: fatal error: ieeefp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ieeefp.h>

/home/sven/Downloads/mono-3.4.0/conftest.c:96: undefined reference to `_finite'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

conftest.c:71:4: error: #error "FAILED"
   #error "FAILED"
    ^

conftest.c:101:31: fatal error: nacl/nacl_dyncode.h: No such file or
directory  #include <nacl/nacl_dyncode.h>

/home/sven/Downloads/mono-3.4.0/conftest.c:102: undefined reference to `dlopen'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

/home/sven/Downloads/mono-3.4.0/conftest.c:111: undefined reference to `kqueue'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

conftest.c:95:13: error: too few arguments to function 'sched_setaffinity'
             sched_setaffinity(0, &mask);

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsocket
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

conftest.c:101:15: error: 'SOL_TCP' undeclared (first use in this function)
   int level = SOL_TCP;

conftest.c:98:22: fatal error: Ws2ipdef.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Ws2ipdef.h>

conftest.c:106:20: error: 'NULL' undeclared (first use in this function)
   gethostbyname2_r(NULL,0,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL);

conftest.c:138:24: fatal error: pthread_np.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pthread_np.h>

/home/sven/Downloads/mono-3.4.0/conftest.c:141: undefined reference to `pthread_attr_get_np'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

/home/sven/Downloads/mono-3.4.0/conftest.c:125: undefined reference to `shm_open'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

/home/sven/Downloads/mono-3.4.0/conftest.c:127: undefined reference to `sqrtf'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

conftest.c:156:23: fatal error: sys/event.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/event.h>

conftest.c:134:8: error: 'struct sockaddr_in' has no member named 'sin_len'
   saddr.sin_len = sizeof (saddr);

conftest.c:134:9: error: 'struct sockaddr_in6' has no member named 'sin6_len'
   saddr6.sin6_len = sizeof (saddr6);

conftest.c:161:23: fatal error: checklist.h: No such file or directory
 #include <checklist.h>

conftest.c:161:22: fatal error: pathconf.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pathconf.h>

conftest.c:129:24: fatal error: attr/xattr.h: No such file or directory
 #include <attr/xattr.h>

conftest.c:162:25: fatal error: sys/extattr.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/extattr.h>

conftest.c:165:24: fatal error: sys/vfstab.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/vfstab.h>

conftest.c:194:24: error: expected expression before ')' token
 if (sizeof ((blksize_t)))

conftest.c:253:39: fatal error: CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h: No such file or directory
 #include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

conftest.c:253:20: fatal error: curses.h: No such file or directory
 #include <curses.h>

conftest.c:225:18: fatal error: term.h: No such file or directory
 #include <term.h>

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsunmath
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Greeting
Sven

Comment: just put some line containing error from configure

Comment: I have edited the question, so the config errors are added ;).